# Format printing 1 instead of True

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in a dict and formats it into strings to be printed in a table.

I'm curious why the following works:

```
A = True
print A
True
```

But with the function

```
def format_dict(dict_in, sep='|'):
    """
    Format a dict into strings
    """
    argument_length = max(len(x) for x in dict_in)
    value_length    = max(len(str(dict_in[x])) for x in dict_in)
    info    = {'arg_len'   : argument_length,
               'val_len'   : value_length,
               'seperator' : sep}
    format_string = '{0:<{arg_len}} {seperator} {1:<{val_len}}'
    header_string = '{0:<{arg_len}} {seperator} {1:^{val_len}}'

    header  = header_string.format('Argument', 'Value', **info)
    strings = []
    for key in sorted(dict_in):
        strings.append(format_string.format(key, dict_in[key], **info))

    return (header, strings)
```

And the dictionary

```
A = {'five': 20000, 'four': 'Long entry', 'one': True, 'three': True, 'two': False}
```

I get

```
B = format_dict(A)
('Argument |   Value   ',
['five  | 20000     ',
'four  | Long entry',
'one   | 1         ',
'three | 1         ',
'two   | 0         '])
```

Why is there no True or False?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a consequence of using the alignment specifier (without that it works as expected). You can force printing the boolean value as `True` or `False` by explicitly specifying the conversion:

```
format_string = '{0:<{arg_len}} {seperator} {1!s:<{val_len}}'
```

– Notice the `!s` part. Specifying this causes the value to be formatted using `__str__`. Omitting it causes `__format__` to be used instead. You can verify what’s happening here:

```
>>> True.__format__('')
'True'
>>> True.__format__('<5')
'    1'
>>> True.__str__()
'True'
```

Comment: I managed to work around it by wrapping the arg, `dict_in[key]` with `str(dict_in[key])`, dunno how I feel about it though.

Comment: @polkid Uh … any particular reason for not using the clean solution presented in this answer?

Comment: Hadn't seen it yet! Testing it out currently. Creating a test with many different size dicts and types within. For my learning, what makes yours cleaner than mine?

Comment: @polkid It doesn’t require you to manually convert data, you put all the formatting where it belongs – into the format string – rather than leaking it into different parts of the code.